# Question mark in use with colon

Tags: formatting, punctuation

Do you use a question mark in hand when you use a colon, if yes how?

`I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug` is the title of the service.

> Should I place the order in: I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug
>
> Should I place the order in?: I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug
>
> Should I place the order in:? I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug

Answer (score 3):

Your problem is that your givens are incorrect. You don't need a colon, and you have the question mark in the wrong spot.

Stripped of the confusing detail, your sentence reads

> Should I place the order in X?

You don't need a colon before the *X* in this sentence structure. You have a question; you aren't introducing a thought or a list.

Separately, your entire thought is a question, so the question mark properly belongs at the end.

Since your service has title caps, that's generally sufficient to set it off from the framing question. If you're really concerned about reader comprehension, you can make the service name italic or enclose it in quotes. If you use quotes, the question mark is not part of the quoted (or formatted) material, so it falls outside them.

> Should I place the order in *I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug*?
>
> Should I place the order in "I Will Fix Any Error Or Bug"?